# Javascript to ignore changes of <select> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript that Disables submit button unless original form data has changed, I want the script to ignore the changes of `<select>` tag. Please help me achieve that.

The code:

```
$(function(){

    $('form')
        .each(function(){
            $(this).data('serialized', $(this).serialize())
        })
        .on('change input', function(){
            $(this)             
                .find('input:submit, button:submit')
                    .attr('disabled', $(this).serialize() == $(this).data('serialized'))
            ;
         })
        .find('input:submit, button:submit')
            .attr('disabled', true)
    ;

});
```

Thanks

Comment: `.on('change', 'input', function(){` might make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if the event is triggered by a `select` element. If it does, prevent further execution of the code.

```
.on('change input', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName !== 'SELECT') {
    $(this)             
      .find('input:submit, button:submit')
      .attr('disabled', $(this).serialize() == $(this).data('serialized'));
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the select tag when serializing

```
$(function(){

    $('form')
        .each(function(){
            $(this).data('serialized', $(this).not('select').serialize())
        })
        .on('change input', function(){
            $(this)             
                .find('input:submit, button:submit')
                    .attr('disabled', $(this).not('select').serialize() == $(this).not('select').data('serialized'))
            ;
         })
        .find('input:submit, button:submit')
            .attr('disabled', true)
    ;

});
```

What this code is now doing is

1. Taking the form element and using `$(this)` getting hold of everything inside the form
2. By using `.not('select')`, it says - take everything in the form except the select tag
3. By doing `.serialize()`, it says - take a snapshot of the elements inside the form, except the `select` tag
4. By taking a snapshot, we can then compare that snapshot with the snapshot during the time of submission. If the snapshots are same, that means nothing changed and hence the button should be disabled.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but still, on changing the values of the select tag the submit button gets unlocked for submission.

Comment: probably because you need to discard the select options - .not('select optoin')